# Can anyone reverse this method?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm reading midi pitchwheel messages with this method ( from here http://www.blitter.com/~russtopia/MIDI/~jglatt/tech/midispec/wheel.htm )that combines 2 hex bytes into a 14bit unsigned short. It is working pretty well but now I'm trying to send out pitchwheel messages which need to be in the 2 bytes hex format. Does anyone know how to reverse this method so that it will take a integer like 12401 and return two bytes?

```
unsigned short CombineBytes(unsigned char First, unsigned char Second)
{
    unsigned short _14bit;
    _14bit = (unsigned short)Second;
    _14bit <<= 7;
    _14bit |= (unsigned short)First;
    return(_14bit);
}
```

This is my bad attempt:

```
unsigned char CreateBytes(unsigned short value)
{
    unsigned char First;
    unsigned char Second;
    unsigned char FullValue;

    FullValue = (unsigned short)value;
    First = FullValue;
    First >>= 7;
    Second |= (unsigned short) value;
    return(First, Second);
}
```

Comment: Show your attempt. We are here to help, not do your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
first  = (combined & 0x3f80) >> 7; // 0b11111110000000
second = (combined & 0x007f);      // 0b00000001111111
```

Comment: This doesn't address the attempt to return two values from the function.